# Execute a shell command

Tags: shell, rust

I want to execute a shell command in **Rust**. In **Python** I can do this:

```
import os
cmd = r'echo "test" >> ~/test.txt'
os.system(cmd)
```

But Rust only has `std::process::Command`. How can I execute a shell command like `cd xxx && touch abc.txt`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should *really* avoid `system`.  What it does depends on what shell is in use and what operating system you're on (your example almost certainly won't do what you expect on Windows).

If you really, desperately *need* to invoke some commands with a shell, you can do *marginally* better by just executing the shell directly (like using the `-c` switch for bash).

If, for some reason, the above isn't feasible *and* you can *guarantee* your program will *only* run on systems where the shell in question is available *and* users *will not* be running anything else...

...then you can just use the [`system`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/libc/x86_64-pc-windows-msvc/libc/fn.system.html) call from [`libc`](https://crates.io/crates/libc) just as you would from regular C.  This counts as FFI, so you'll probably want to look at [`std::ffi::CStr`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/ffi/struct.CStr.html).

Answer (score 40):

Everybody is looking for:

```
use std::process::Command;

fn main() {
    let output = Command::new("echo")
        .arg("Hello world")
        .output()
        .expect("Failed to execute command");

    assert_eq!(b"Hello world\n", output.stdout.as_slice());
}
```

For more information and examples, see the [docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html).

You wanted to simulate `&&`. `std::process::Command` has a [`status`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.status) method that returns a [`Result<T>`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/io/type.Result.html) and `Result` implements [`and_then`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/result/enum.Result.html#method.and_then). You can use `and_then` like a `&&` but in more safe Rust way :)

Comment: Except that `Command::new ("cd").arg ("foo").status()` will always [fail](https://play.integer32.com/?gist=572ca6d0639209b4933d114c151dde71&version=stable&mode=debug)…

Comment: @Jmb Do you know why?

Comment: Because `cd` is not an executable, it is an internal shell command and as such can't be run directly from a non-shell program. You could always do `Command::new ("/bin/sh").args (&["-c", "cd", "foo"])` to run the command in a shell but that's a no-op that won't affect the calling process.

Comment: that didn't work for me, I recieved a runtime error. when I was running on windows I had to do Command::new("cmd")
this than ran the code fine.

Comment: @DevinB Rust code works on Windows and Linux but the parameters are system dependent. Example is for Linux. Feel free to edit this answer if you know example that works both on Windows and Linux.

Comment: @Jmb wow that's an excellent answer in search of a question, I know I've been having problems with that (cd not being an executable, or similar things) many times but explaining is succinctly makes it very clear(er) suddenly.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone looking for a way to set the current directory for the subprocess running the command i. e. run "ls" in some dir there's [`Command::current_dir`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.current_dir). Usage:

```rust
use std::process::Command;

Command::new("ls")
        .current_dir("/bin")
        .spawn()
        .expect("ls command failed to start");
```