# How can I open another console window

Tags: rust

I am trying to open a new console terminal from Rust. With the help of documentation, I was capable of starting a terminal in the current terminal window, but not in another one.

For example, imagine I have one folder with two files `main.py` and `bb.py` and the following code does the thing I want

```py
import os
os.system("start cmd /K python bb.py")
```

It opens a new terminal, and in this new terminal the command `python bb.py` is executed. How can I do this in Rust?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execute a shell command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31666936/execute-a-shell-command)

Comment: Looks like it doesn't work on Windows. I'm getting an error: thread 'main' panicked at 'Failed to execute command: Error { kind: NotFound, message: "program not found" }', src\main.rs:7:10
note: run with `RUST_BACKTRACE=1` environment variable to display a backtrace